# [Excel][VBA] Look up value from another sheet and copy it's BG

Tags: excel, vba

I have been assigned simple task (at first I thought so), to monitor input into excel and if there is number (like 0000068145) I need to highlight it with it's colors. So I created two sheets Sheet1 and Database. In Database I keep my data like this:

[image: Database Sheet here]

So I used this code and it called whenever I change something :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


End Sub
```

And I thought about using Vlookup, but it will retrieve only value as far as I know.

So how would you realize this kind of operation?

I can't use Vlookup, and I really need "database" to be separate from main sheet.

Sorry for my english

Comment: You could store the `ThemeColor` and `TintAndShade` property values against their corresponding number, then just look up this data and use the values to colour the cell. If you don't know the property values, Record Macro is your friend.

Comment: What about conditioning formatting? I see the possibility here for it. maybe it would be better way to do it? Hmm... But setting Conditional for every number is pain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach using `Worksheet_Change` is correct.

Put the following into the `Sheet1` code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim oCell As Range, oDBCell As Range
 Dim dbWS As Worksheet
 Dim lColor As Long
 Set dbWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")
 For Each oCell In Target
  Set oDBCell = dbWS.Range("A:A").Find(what:=oCell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
  If Not oDBCell Is Nothing Then
   lColor = oDBCell.Interior.Color
   oCell.Interior.Color = lColor
  End If
 Next
End Sub
```

Your "Database" sheet must be named `Database`.

Now if you put some value into a cell in `Sheet1` which is also in column `A` of your database sheet, then the color is copied from this database sheet.